# Updating entity as whole vs updating particular columns in separation

Tags: android, database, android-room

I can't understand why would you write a method to update particular column of entity instead of using room's @update annotation to perform update of given entity object.

The following example is taken from one of [google's sample apps](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/data/source/local/TasksDao.kt#L73):

```
@Dao
interface TasksDao {
    @Update
    suspend fun updateTask(task: Task): Int

    @Query("UPDATE tasks SET completed = :completed WHERE entryid = :taskId")
    suspend fun updateCompleted(taskId: String, completed: Boolean)
}
```

---

1. What's the point of providing a method to update the entity by passing its `id` and new value of `completed` column?
2. Author implemented `updateTask()` method which takes the task object as parameter, so why not to pass a modified version of the object in which `completed` property would be set to expected value?
3. How is the `updateCompleted()` method better than `updateTask()`? It doesn't seem practical to provide a specialized method to update each column of entity in separation. It would be ridiculous as the number of columns grows.
4. When should I use each of these approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be more efficient to use the **updateCompleted** method as you just need to have the id available so you then don't need to obtain all the other values and then create an object just to change a specific value.

Using such a method also has the advantage of potentially making the code clearer to read as the objective of the function is quite clear. The is also a reduced chance of inadvertently changing values that shouldn't be changed.

Of course the disadvantage is that more code is generated and thus the APK will be larger. So if the APK size is of concern, you may want to reduce methods to the minimum.